# Why is there a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, string, exception

I am writing a program that is supposed to scan all chars in a line and see if there is a ")_". If there is, then the program checks if there are any nested parentheses and then converts certain strings in the parentheses. However, every time I run the program there is a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I don't know why, since I already subtracted the strings length by 2 so it should be a valid index, as shown below:

```
for(int i=line.length()-2;i>0;i--){
```

This is the line that is causing the problem:

```
if(line.charAt(i+1)=='{'){
```

Here is my code:

```
private static int checkNestedParen(String line){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=line.length()-1;i>=0;i-- ){
        if(line.charAt(i)==')')
            count++;
        if(line.charAt(i)=='('&&count==0)
            return i;
        if(line.charAt(i)=='(')
            count--;
    }
    return 0;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        char toChecko=')';
        for(int i=line.length()-2;i>0;i--){
            if(line.charAt(i)==toChecko&&line.charAt(i+1) == '_'){
                String substring = line.substring(0,i);
                int openParen = checkNestedParen(substring);
                a = line.substring(openParen, i);
                beforeLine=line.substring(0, openParen);
            }
            if(line.charAt(i+1)=='{'){
                int startBracker = i+2;
                int endBracker = line.indexOf('}',i+2);
                String n = line.substring(startBracker, endBracker);
                line =  beforeLine + "/pochhammer{" + a + "}{" + n + "}";
            }
            else {
                char n = line.charAt(i+1);
                line = beforeLine + "/pochhammer{" + a + "}{" + n + "}";
            }
        }
        writer.println(line);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your stack trace, and please clearly identify the line that is causing the exception by labeling it in your posted code.

Comment: @JasonC, I identified the line that is causing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Then, given your edit, it appears EJP's answer is the most relevant. You must be shortening `line` when you modify it in that inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing `line` inside the loop. If you change it to something shorter than the current value of `i` or `i-1`, depending on which line throws the exception, you will get the exception next time around.